# Wrong resource Group when I create a Managed Certificate in Azure

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, certificate

I would like to create a free `Managed Certificate` for my web app.
When I create the certificate I get the error **Resource under Resource group xxx not found**... Despite the error, the certificate is created, but also the inexistent resource group is created. The resource group is an old group I deleted times ago.

Everythings seems to be worked correctly but I would like to have a consistent situation.

I let you see in details:

[image]

What you see in the image above is my web app that is in the resource group `dev-p...l-rg-westeu`.

The I go in the **TLS/SSL settings** page (or in the **TLS/SSL settings (preview)** page.. nothing change, I get same error) and I create a managed certificate.. Here it is what I get:

[image]

I get the error that the web app xxx is not found under resource group `dev-m...o-rg-westeu`.. That's correct!! Because the web app is under the resource group `dev-p...l-rg-westeu`, not under `dev-m...o-rg-westeu`.

However the certificate is created, but under the wrong resource group:

[image]

Then I deleted the certificate. I deleted also the wrong resource group, because I do not need it and try and try again. Always same error. I also tryed to create the certificate via powershall:

```
 New-AzWebAppCertificate -ResourceGroupName "dev-p...l-rg-westeu" -WebAppName "xxx" -Name "xxxx" -HostName "xxxx" -SslState 'SniEnabled'
```

As you can see I set explicitely the resource group name. But the certificate is always created in the wrong resource group. I debugged the command. It seems a cache exists. Can I clear it? Could it be the problem?

I also deleted and created a new web app. Nothing...

Can you help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have tested in our environment with your given PowerShell command and can able to add in our own resource group as well.

We have only one resource group in which we created an app service

[image]

Run the below command for [***`create an App Service Managed Certificate`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebappcertificate?view=azps-7.3.0#description) for the given WebApp in our resource group.

```
 New-AzWebAppCertificate -ResourceGroupName "RGNAME" -WebAppName "appname" -Name "nameofCert" -HostName "www.name.com"
```

After running its added succesfully to our resource group.
***Please make sure that you have provided the correct resource group where your app service is created. And you have deleted the old resource group successfully*** .

Once the the command successfully run make a refresh of the Azure portal then goto  ***TLS/SSL settings (preview)*** binding and check the certificate.

***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

Certificate added to our own resource group

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

- ***MICROSOFT Q&A-*** [***Azure App Service creates certificate under defunct Resource Group***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/680851/azure-app-service-creates-certificate-under-defunc.html) as suggested by @[***SnehaAgrawal-MSFT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/141732/snehaagrawal-msft.html) & [***This discussion***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/625735/app-service-ssl-certificate-created-with-incorrect.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you... I think there is a bug on Azure.  What I understood the problem was the `Service Plan` was created under a resource group. I call it `A` , to make it simple. Then, the service plan was moved under the resource group `B`. `A` was correctly deleted.
Despite `A` did not exists anymore, when I tryed to create the certificate, the certificate was created under `A` resource group even if I got the message that `A` did not exists anymore.
No support from Microsoft. So I deleted the service plan and I recreated it. Everything worked. I discovered that debugging powershell command.

Comment: Hello @Ciccio, `I think there is a bug on Azure` Not sure . AFAIK, Once we deleted the resource group there is no way our resources will be created on the same . We have to make sure that we have deleted our resource group successfully and mention the resource group name when we created certificate .

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT .. surely something is wrong.. I had done all steps you said and ti did not work. When I created the certificate via powershell I mentioned the resource group (in the post you can see the command) but it was like it was ignored. What I understood debugging command is that, in some way, the app service plan was still linked to the resource group I had deleted (the plan had been moved between rg) and the command used the deleted group. I wrote to MSFT with all screens. No answer. I dont think the problem is on certificate creation but when you move resoruces between groups.

Comment: However, the problem was solved deleting the app service plan and creating a new app service plan in the only existing group. Everything worked. However I think it is easy replicate a problem:
1. Create resource group A;
2. Create app service plan and app in A;
3. Create resource group B;
4. Move app and app service plan from A to B;
5. Delete resource group A;
6. Create certificate.

Output: Error message but certificate created.
That is what I think